# Where can I find more information about the `view` command?

Tags: bash

I was looking through the `history` on a server and saw my coworker use the `view` command on a file.

Best I can tell, it looks at your `$EDITOR` and then opens that file with it.

I want to know more about how it works, but it is proving difficult. Using `man` or `info` on `view` just returns the help page for your `$EDITOR`. Doesn't have a `help` page and googling it is obviously hard.

Any idea?

Comment: `view` is usually an alias for `vi` (not `$EDITOR`).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Okay that would make sense. I was only able to test on systems with vi/vim installed

Answer (score 1):

Using `man view` one is directed to the man page for `vim`.  Inside I found this:

```
view      Start in read-only mode.  You will be protected from writing the files.  Can also be done with the "-R" argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my system interesting.  Starting with:

```
type view
view is /usr/bin/view
```

So, what is that?

```
file /usr/bin/view
/usr/bin/view: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/view

file /etc/alternatives/view
/etc/alternatives/view: symbolic link to /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

So, in the end (on Ubuntu based systems at least), it's a symlink managed by `update-alternatives`.

```
update-alternatives --config view

    There are 2 choices for the alternative view (providing /usr/bin/view).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```